# Does $|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|\leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$ hold?

Tags: inequality

I am reading "Introduction to Set Theory and Topology" (in Japanese) by Kazuo Matsuzaka.

> Problem 7 on p. 263:
> Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space.
> Prove that $d:S\times S\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

I made my answer as follows:

> We need to prove that for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $d'((x,y),(x',y'))<\delta\implies |d(x,y)-d(x',y')|<\epsilon$, where $d'$ is the metric on $S\times S$.
> By the triangle inequality, $d(x,y)\leq d(x,x')+d(x',y')+d(y',y)$.
> So, $d(x,y)-d(x',y')\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y').$
> By the triangle inequality, $d(x',y')\leq d(x',x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y')$.
> So, $d(x',y')-d(x,y)\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y').$
> Therefore, $|d(x,y)-d(x',y')|\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y').$
> In general, $|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|\leq n\max\{|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|\}\leq n\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$ holds.
> So, $|d(x,y)-d(x',y')|\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y')\leq 2\sqrt{d(x,x')^2+d(y,y')^2}=2 d'((x,y),(x',y'))$.
> Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number.
> Let $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.
> Then, $d'((x,y),(x',y'))<\delta\implies |d(x,y)-d(x',y')|<\epsilon$

I found someone's answer to Problem 7 on the Internet.

Someone's answer is like the following:

> We need to prove that for any positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a positive real number $\delta$ such that $d'((x,y),(x',y'))<\delta\implies |d(x,y)-d(x',y')|<\epsilon$, where $d'$ is a metric on $S\times S$.
> By the triangle inequality, $d(x,y)\leq d(x,x')+d(x',y')+d(y',y)$.
> So, $d(x,y)-d(x',y')\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y').$
> By the triangle inequality, $d(x',y')\leq d(x',x)+d(x,y)+d(y,y')$.
> So, $d(x',y')-d(x,y)\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y').$
> Therefore, $|d(x,y)-d(x',y')|\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y').$
> So, $|d(x,y)-d(x',y')|\leq d(x,x')+d(y,y')\leq \sqrt{2}\sqrt{d(x,x')^2+d(y,y')^2}=\sqrt{2} d'((x,y),(x',y'))$.
> Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number.
> Let $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$.
> Then, $d'((x,y),(x',y'))<\delta\implies |d(x,y)-d(x',y')|<\epsilon$

My question is here:

> Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be real numbers.
> Does $|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|\leq \sqrt{n}\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}$ hold?

I know when $n=2$, the above inequality holds.

Comment: Yes, the inequality is immediate fron C-S inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: By Cauchy - Schwarz inequality, $|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|=|(1,\dots,1)\cdot (|x_1|,\dots,|x_n|)|\leq\sqrt{1+\dots+1}\cdot\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}=\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}.$

Comment: See the relation between the arithmetic and quadratic mean: $\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}{n}\leq\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2}{n}}$ for $x_1,\dots,x_n\geq 0$.